# Build folder not recognized in pm2 service

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, vps, pm2

I'm running my node+react app on vps ubuntu machine using ssh.
I used nginx, pm2 for running my node js server, but when I check my logs it shows the following error:

```
App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2020-09-16T07:05:03: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
PM2        | 2020-09-16T07:06:18: PM2 log: Reloading logs...
PM2        | 2020-09-16T07:06:18: PM2 log: Reloading logs for process id 0
PM2        | 2020-09-16T07:38:58: PM2 log: Stopping app:server id:0
PM2        | 2020-09-16T07:38:58: PM2 log: App [server:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2020-09-16T07:38:58: PM2 log: pid=6888 msg=process killed
PM2        | 2020-09-16T07:38:58: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2020-09-16T07:38:58: PM2 log: App [server:0] online 

0|server   | Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/root/repos/IRS-Ecommerce/IRS- 
Ecommerce/build/index.html'

/root/.pm2/logs/server-out.log last 15 lines:
0|server   | Server is up and running at port : 8080
0|server   | MongoDB connected successfully!
```

My node js server file where I'm sending my react app in response:

```
 app.use(express.static("IRS-Ecommerce/build"));
 app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "IRS-Ecommerce", "build", "index.html"));
 });
```

I've run npm build in my react app and build folder is present there, but it is showing this error that index.html is not there. I've checked the path, it is correct.

When I access public IP, my react app shows up which means it is working. But why am I seeing this error here?[image]

Answer (score 0):

`/root/repos/IRS-Ecommerce/IRS-  Ecommerce/build/index.html` double IRS-
Ecommerce orz

Comment: It is double only. That's not a mistake. If I cd into this path, it opens my build folder. I added image to my question, you can see.